# Add a node_module as a javascript src in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Seems crazy that this isn't as easy as it should be.

My file structure:

```
node_modules/
public/
 -- css/
 -- js/
 -- index.html
```

In `index.html`, I try to load a file in a `node_module`, like so:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular-ui-sortable/src/sortable.js"></script>
```

But, this doesn't work. My error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '<'
```

I check the resources, and `sortable.js` is being loaded with the content of `index.html`. I've seen this issue when the designated javascript file can't be found.

Is this just some wonky issue with nodeJS? Is there some black magic needed to simply load a javascript file into html?

Comment: What are you using to serve your static assets?  Are you serving up the node_modules directory?

Comment: Make sure to include require.js if your node module depends on it. Many node_modules are not available for running in the browser and are only server side.

Comment: I suspect whatever is serving static assets is set to docroot at `public/` which means it will not recognize anything higher. Maybe use browserify?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're doing something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public');
```

Which would produce the kind of result your seeing.  Suggested fix:

add

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules');
```

and change the url to

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular-ui-sortable/src/sortable.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is true, though it's worth noting as well that not all node modules will work correctly in the browser, and many are not particularly 'browser friendly' (e.g. assign to global variables, etc) unless reworked.

Comment: your suspicions are correct. I tried the fix to no avail - same error. Really, I'm just trying to stop using `uglify` during development because debugging becomes tedious on a single minified js file. Seems like either using `browserify` or some other `grunt` plugin to include all my js files would be optimal.

Comment: You should look into using source maps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and this fix worked for me:

in you app.js in node add this:

```
app.use('/node_modules',express.static(path.join(__dirname , 'node_modules')));
```

and in your index.html add this:

```
<script src="node_modules/<packagename>/<filename>.js"></script>
```

If you worry about importing unwanted packages from node_models folders you could specify the routing to a specific folder of the desired package. Hope this helps.